# Getting server-specific error code 0 when trying to start tomcat service

Tags: java, tomcat

I installed `Tomcat 6` on a windows7  and it will not start as a service. I'm running it with `jdk 1.5`
It runs when I start it with tomcat6.exe.
i am getting a error:

```
"Windows could not start the Apache Tomcat server on Local Computer.For more information ,review the System Event Log.If this is a non-Microsoft service,contact the service vendor ,and refer to service -specific error code 0".
```

Comment: Have you taken a look in the Tomcat log files?